# How should I pass data between classes and application layers?

Tags: c#, asp.net

For example, if I am creating a 3 layer application (data / business / UI) and the data layer is grabbing single or multiple records.  Do I convert everything from data layer into generic list/collections before sending to the business layer?  Is it ok to send data tables? What about sending info back to the data layer?

If I use objects/lists, are these members of the Data or Business layers?  Can I use the same objects to pass to and from the layers?

Here is some pseudo code:

object user with email / password

in UI layer, user inputs email / password. UI layer does validation and then I assume creates a new object user to pass to business layer which does further validation and passes same object to Data layer to insert record.  Is this correct?

I am new to .NET (come from 8+ years of ASP VBScript background) and trying to get up to speed on the 'right' way to do things.

Comment: @developer take a look at Mark Brittingham code, I think that is the best option.  I like joel's approach too but Mark got me thinking :).

Comment: @JonH - Thanks! I am learning .net as fast as possible, but I am still a bit of a noob.  8+ years of ASP VBScript makes it easier to learn, but still stuggling.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

*I am updating this answer because comments left by Developr seem to indicate that he would like a bit more detail.*

The short answer to your question is **Yes** you'll want to use class instances (objects) to mediate the interface between your UI and your Business Logic Layer.  The BLL and DAL will communicate as discussed below.  You should not be passing SqlDataTables or SqlDataReaders around.

The simple reasons as to why: objects are type-safe, offer Intellisense support, permit you to make additions or alterations at the Business Layer that aren't necessarily found in the database, and give you some freedom to unlink the application from the database so that you can maintain a consistent BLL interface even as the database changes (within limits, of course).  It is simply *good programming practice.*

The big picture is that, for any page in your UI, you'll have one or more "models" that you want to display and interact with.  Objects are the way to capture the current state of a model. In terms of process: the UI will request a model (which may be a single object or a list of objects) from the Business Logic Layer (BLL).  The BLL then creates and returns this model - usually using the tools from the Data Access Layer (DAL). If changes are made to the model in the UI, then the UI will send the revised object(s) back to the BLL with instructions as to what to do with them (e.g. insert, update, delete).

.NET is great for this kind of Separation of Concerns because the Generic container classes - and in particular the List<> class - are perfect for this kind of work. They not only permit you to pass the data but they are easily integrated with sophisticated UI controls like grids, lists, etc. via the ObjectDataSource class.  You can implement the full range of operations that you need to develop the UI using ObjectDataSource: "Fill" operations with parameters, CRUD operations, sorting, etc.).

Because this is fairly important, let me make a quick diversion to demonstrate how to define an ObjectDataSource:

```
<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ObjectDataSource1" runat="server" 
    OldValuesParameterFormatString="original_{0}" 
    SelectMethod="GetArticles" 
    OnObjectCreating="OnObjectCreating"
    TypeName="MotivationBusinessModel.ContentPagesLogic">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:SessionParameter DefaultValue="News" Name="category" 
            SessionField="CurPageCategory" Type="String" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

Here, *MotivationBusinessModel* is the namespace for the BLL and *ContentPagesLogic* is the class implementing the logic for, well, Content Pages.  The method for pulling data is "*GetArticles*" and it takes a Parameter called *CurPageCategory*. In this particular case, the ObjectDataSource returns a list of objects that is then used by a grid.  Note that I need to pass session state information to the BLL class so, in the code behind, I have a method "*OnObjectCreating*" that lets me create the object and pass in parameters:

```
public void OnObjectCreating(object sender, ObjectDataSourceEventArgs e)
{
    e.ObjectInstance = new ContentPagesLogic(sessionObj);
}
```

So, this is how it works.  But that begs one very big question - where do the Models / Business Objects come from?  ORMs like Linq to SQL and Subsonic offer code generators that let you create a class for each of your database tables.  That is, these tools say that the model classes should be defined in your DAL and the map directly onto database tables.  Linq to Entities lets you define your objects in a manner quite distinct from the layout of your database but is correspondingly more complex (that is why there is a distinction between Linq to SQL and Linq to Entities).  In essence, it is a BLL solution. Joel and I have said in various places on this thread that, really, the Business Layer is generally where the Models should be defined (although I use a mix of BLL and DAL objects in reality).

Once you decide to do this, how do you implement the mapping from models to the database? Well, you write classes in the BLL to pull the data (using your DAL) and fill the object or list of objects. It is *Business Logic* because the mapping is often accompanied by additional logic to flesh out the Model (e.g. defining the value of derived fields).

Joel creates static Factory classes to implement the model-to-database mapping.  This is a good approach as it uses a well-known pattern and places the mapping right in the construction of the object(s) to be returned.  You always know where to go to see the mapping and the overall approach is simple and straightforward.

I've taken a different approach.  Throughout my BLL, I define *Logic* classes and *Model* classes.  These are generally defined in matching pairs where both classes are defined in the same file and whose names differ by their suffix (e.g. ClassModel and ClassLogic).  The Logic classes know how to work with the Model classes - doing things like Fill, Save ("Upsert"), Delete, and generate feedback for a Model Instance.

In particular, to do the Fill, I leverage methods found in my primary DAL class (shown below) that let me take any class and any SQL query and find a way to create/fill instances of the class using the data returned by the query (either as a single instance or as a list).  That is, the Logic class just grabs a Model class definition, defines a SQL Query and sends them to the DAL.  The result is a single object or list of objects that I can then pass on to the UI. Note that the query may return fields from one table or multiple tables joined together.  At the mapping level, I really don't care - I just want some objects filled.

Here is the first function.  It will take an arbitrary class and map it automatically to all matching fields extracted from a query.  The matching is performed by finding fields whose name matches a property in the class.  If there are extra class fields (e.g. ones that you'll fill using business logic) or extra query fields, they are ignored.

```
    public List<T> ReturnList<T>() where T : new()
    {
        try
        {
            List<T> fdList = new List<T>();
            myCommand.CommandText = QueryString;
            SqlDataReader nwReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();
            Type objectType = typeof (T);
            PropertyInfo[] typeFields = objectType.GetProperties();
            if (nwReader != null)
            {
                while (nwReader.Read())
                {
                    T obj = new T();
                    for (int i = 0; i < nwReader.FieldCount; i++)
                    {
                        foreach (PropertyInfo info in typeFields)
                        {
                            // Because the class may have fields that are *not* being filled, I don't use nwReader[info.Name] in this function.
                            if (info.Name == nwReader.GetName(i))
                            {
                                if (!nwReader[i].Equals(DBNull.Value)) 
                                    info.SetValue(obj, nwReader[i], null);
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    fdList.Add(obj);
                }
                nwReader.Close();
            }
            return fdList;
        }
        catch
        {
            conn.Close();
            throw;
        }
    }
```

This is used in the context of my DAL but the only thing that you have to have in the DAL class is a holder for the QueryString, a SqlCommand object with an open Connection and any parameters. The key is just to make sure the ExecuteReader will work when this is called.  A typical use of this function by my BLL thus looks like:

```
return qry.Command("Select AttendDate, Count(*) as ClassAttendCount From ClassAttend")
          .Where("ClassID", classID)
          .ReturnList<AttendListDateModel>();
```

You can also implement support for anonymous classes like so:

```
    public List<T> ReturnList<T>(T sample)
    {
        try
        {
            List<T> fdList = new List<T>();
            myCommand.CommandText = QueryString;
            SqlDataReader nwReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();
            var properties = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(sample);
            if (nwReader != null)
            {
                while (nwReader.Read())
                {
                    int objIdx = 0;
                    object[] objArray = new object[properties.Count];
                    for (int i = 0; i < nwReader.FieldCount; i++)
                    {
                        foreach (PropertyDescriptor info in properties) // FieldInfo info in typeFields)
                        {
                            if (info.Name == nwReader.GetName(i))
                            {
                                objArray[objIdx++] = nwReader[info.Name];
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    fdList.Add((T)Activator.CreateInstance(sample.GetType(), objArray));
                }
                nwReader.Close();
            }
            return fdList;
        }
        catch
        {
            conn.Close();
            throw;
        }
    }
```

A call to this looks like:

```
var qList = qry.Command("Select QueryDesc, UID, StaffID From Query")
               .Where("SiteID", sessionObj.siteID)
               .ReturnList(new { QueryDesc = "", UID = 0, StaffID=0 });
```

Now qList is a generic list of dynamically-created class instances defined on the fly.

Let's say you have a function in your BLL that takes a pull-down list as an argument and a request to fill the list with data.  Here is how you could fill the pull down with the results retrieved above:

```
foreach (var queryObj in qList)
{
    pullDownList.Add(new ListItem(queryObj.QueryDesc, queryObj.UID.ToString()));
}
```

In short, we can define anonymous Business Model classes on the fly and then fill them just by passing some (on the fly) SQL to the DAL.  Thus, the BLL is very easy to update in response to evolving needs in the UI.

---

One last note: If you are concerned that defining and passing around objects wastes memory, you shouldn't be: if you use a SqlDataReader to pull the data and place it into the objects that make up your list, you'll  only have one in-memory copy (the list) as the reader iterates through in a read-only, forward-only fashion.  Of course, if you use DataAdapter and Table classes (etc.) at your data access layer then you would be incurring needless overhead (which is why you shouldn't do it).

Comment: I definitely see some things in here to like, though I would re-write to use an iterator block with an IEnumerable rather than a List.

Comment: Mark I know I already upvoted you, but thank you for the further changes this is very cool.

Comment: Mark, Thanks for your detailed response.  I am trying to wrap my head around it.  Once I have consumed a object from my DAL and need to send it back to the DAL (updating a record), so I send it as the same type of object (eg - list)?  Should I setup my class files so that I have DAL, BLL, BO/DTO, and UI to keep it all neat and tidy?

Comment: @JonH - You're welcome.  @Joel - thanks for the comments, I hope you didn't take my comments elsewhere as insulting: I *like* what you've done. I just went through a period awhile back where I wanted to create the ultimate DAL and ended up with this approach.  I was reading Skeet's book at the time so I was trying out all kinds of cool stuff (the book is extraordinary - get it if you haven't already).  RE: using IEnumerable rather than List<> - I agree in concept and I'd make the change if I had time and need but Lists have worked out great so I have little incentive so far.

Comment: @developr - In practice, Lists of Business Objects (BOs - also called models) are used to supply tables/lists/grids in the UI with data from the BLL. Single Business Objects are used to supply information to a UI when I am displaying just one record's worth of information.  I always think in terms of the UI/BLL interface when designing architecture.  I'll figure out how to get the BLL to drive the DAL as needed (that's more the plumbing).  Also, while it is often the case that a BO corresponds to a record from a table, it isn't *always* the case.

Comment: @developr - When changes are made at the UI level and I need to store them, I'll copy from the UI controls to a BO instance and send it to the BLL.  This is always done on a single object (I can't think of any exceptions, anyway). Even if you are editing a record in a grid holding lots of records, the changes get posted back one record at a time via the ObjectDataSource. -continued-

Comment: @developr - Thus, my BLL classes almost always have one or more of: A) a Fill method that returns a single instance of a BO based on a unique ID (UID), B) a Fill method that returns a List<ModelClass>, C) an Upsert method that the UI calls to feed a BO to the BLL for storage, and D) a Delete method where a UID or other criteria identifies the record to delete.

Comment: @developr - One last thing.  In my architecture, I just have three namespaces: one for the UI, one for the BLL and one for the DAL.  The Business Objects (models) are defined within the BLL namespace and almost always right in the same file where the corresponding "Logic" class that uses it is defined (the exception coming when more than one BLL logic class uses a particular BO class).  I do not use a separate namespace for the BO classes as it just complicates matters.

Comment: I'd like this answer to be accepted!
Very very informative...only because I deal with this type of programming ALL the time.

Answer (score 13):

In general, I think it is better to send objects rather than data tables.  With objects, each layer knows what it is receiving (which objects with what properties etc.).   You get compile time safety with objects, you can't accidentally misspell a property name etc. and it forces an inherent contract between the two tiers.

Joshua also brings up a good point, by using your custom object, you are also decoupling the other tiers from the data tier.  You can always populate your custom object from another data source and the other tiers will be none the wiser.  With a SQL data table, this will probably not be so easy.

Joel also made a good point.  Having your data layer aware of your business objects is not a good idea for the same reason as making your business and UI layers aware of the specifics of your data layer.

Comment: Not just that but if you use objects you allow the data layer to be changed out in the future. If you were passing a SqlDataReader or something you've just coupled the Data and Business layer together and force your data layer to always use SQL.

Comment: Using objects make it's harder to change out the data layer, not easier, because any substitute data layer also has to know about your objects.  I prefer a sort of intermediate translation layer that completely decouples code that knows about business objects from code that knows about data access.

Comment: @Joel I see what you are saying.  I agree that passing the business objects into the data layer is not advisable.

Comment: I agree with Joel here but I prefer even more flexibility than a simple mapping layer: there are ways of querying with objects that don't even require you to define the mapping ahead of time as he does with his Factory classes.

Comment: @Joel Coehoorn: If you do that, aren't you just moving the problem to your intermediate layer, which has to know about both the data and the business? Isn't it precisely the same problem, but in a (possibly) different assembly?

Comment: So, in my data layer, I should populate a generic list with my objects, that gets returned to my business layer.  How do I get data back into the DAL?  Also, what about when I push data from my UI to my BLL?  One other thing, where do I define the objects? In DAL, BLL, or a new layer?

Comment: @developrr - what do you mean how do I get back into the DAL?  Its like this UI->BLL->DAL and then UI<-BLL<-DAL.

Comment: @developrr - actually, the DAL is generally used to provide a layer of abstraction from the raw SQL management code.  The BLL uses this abstraction to prepare objects that are then passed to or received from the UI.  The BLL also is responsible doing the right thing with them: if "Fill" is called with an object, you fill it (the BLL class determining what kind of code you are working on).  If "Save" is called, you save it - that is, you transcribe the Data Object fields to database parameters (using facilities provided by the DAL) and then executing the save.

Comment: @SnOrfus - not really.  For all the hype about separation of concerns, with just business and data layers it's still normal for a change in one layer to force code changes and re-compiles in other layers as well.  The purpose of the translation layer is to insulate the data and business layers from each other.  If your business layer changes, it does probably propogate to the translation layer, _but no further_.  The same is true for the data layer. And the translation layer can often be written by a code generator.

Comment: @Mark Brittingham - so in my business layer, I populate the object (just like the objects I am returning from the data layer), then send that to the data layer to actually update the database?

Comment: @developr - you'll populate the objects in the BLL *using* the data layer and then pass them to the UI. Your BLL will then get objects back from the UI to update - which it will do by using the DAL. Now, you can do most of this work in the BLL OR the DAL (the low-level mapping, saving, etc.) It all depends on how the DAL is built and the complexity of the mapping (Class structure=db structure -> do it in DAL, Class Structure loosely coupled to db structure -> do it in BLL). I have rewritten my answer to make it much more complete and to cover all of these things - take a look!

Comment: BTW - once you get the hang of this it will seem entirely natural!

Answer (score 7):

There are nearly as many "correct" ways to do this as there are programming teams in the world.  That said, what *I* like to do is build a factory for each of my business objects that looks something like this:

```
public static class SomeBusinessObjectFactory
{
   public static SomeBusinessObject FromDataRow(IDataRecord row)
   {
       return new SomeBusinessObject() { Property1 = row["Property1"], Property2 = row["Property2"] ... };
   }
}
```

I also have a generic translation method that I use to call these factories:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> TranslateQuery(IEnumerable<IDatarecord> source, Func<IDatarecord, T> Factory)
{
    foreach (IDatarecord item in source)
        yield return Factory(item);
}
```

Depending on what your team prefers, the size of the project, etc, these factory objects and translator can live with the business layer or data layer, or even an extra "translation" assembly/layer.

Then my data layer will have code that looks like this:

```
private SqlConnection GetConnection()
{
    var conn = new SqlConnection( /* connection string loaded from config file */ );
    conn.Open();
    return conn;
}

private static IEnumerable<IDataRecord> ExecuteEnumerable(this SqlCommand command)
{
    using (var rdr = command.ExecuteReader())
    { 
        while (rdr.Read())
        {
            yield return rdr;
        }
    }
}

public  IEnumerable<IDataRecord> SomeQuery(int SomeParameter)
{
    string sql = " .... ";

    using (var cn = GetConnection())
    using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, cn))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Someparameter", SqlDbType.Int).Value = SomeParameter;
        return cmd.ExecuteEnumerable();
    }
}
```

And then I can put it all together like this:

```
 SomeGridControl.DataSource = TranslateQuery(SomeQuery(5), SomeBusinessObjectFactory.FromDataRow);
```

Comment: @Joel - very nice as well :).

Comment: @Joel Coehoorn - Where are you doing SomeGridControl.DataSource = TranslateQuery(SomeQuery(5), SomeBusinessObjectFactory.FromDataRow); this at in the UI ?  Also you are stating SomeBusinessObject.Factory.FromDataRow but you did not show how you got the row of data.

Comment: Sounds like a good idea, but I think I need to learn more c# concepts so I can fully understand the solution.

Comment: @developr - These answers are from people who have a lot of C# experience and programming experience.  I suggest you start with something simple, all of this code is very generic, if you are just beginning you may want to stick to a non-generic concrete implementation.  I know that may sound strange, but this as well as Mark's code is pretty intense and does require C# experience.

Comment: @JonH - The Grid code is actually a bad example, since it would represent presentation code calling directly into the data/translation layers.  Real code would do that from the business layer, but I wanted to show a quick example so it would be clear how the data code can be used.

Comment: Thanks guys... my biggest problem right now is that I am trying to skip the beginner stuff.  I have been dragging my feet on .net for many years as I have been supporting legacy ASP Vbscript apps.  Now it is time to convert those apps to ASP.net (large ecommerce site with lots of sub apps) and I really don't know where to start.  As a result I have been learning as much about patterns and best practices.   It is hard to find the middle ground between using sqldatasources on the ui (dont want to do that) and full blown 3 layer with full abstraction and loose coupling.

Comment: @developr The thing to do is use an ObjectDataSource rather than SqlDataSource.  You can easily point an ObjectDataSource at your business layer.  The business layer calls into the data layer (or translation code if you follow my example) which in turn talks directly to the database.  Then your aspx markup and code-behind are your presentation layer.  More than that, if you want you can use something called an ORM, or object relational mapper, to replace your data layer.  Then the only "layer" code you have to write yourself is the business code.

Answer (score 1):

I´d add a new layer, **ORM Object Relational Mapping**, with the responsability to transform data from Data layer into bussiness objects collections. I think that using objects in your bussiness model is the best practice.

Comment: Writing data access code is steeling from the customer! Thats the problems with the solutions above..

Answer (score 1):

Whatever means you use to pass data between the layers of your application, just be sure that the implementation details of each layer do not leak into the others. You should be able to change how the data in the relational database is stored without modifying any of the code in the business objects layers (other than serialization of course).

A tight coupling between the design of the business objects and the relational data model is extremely irritating and is a waste of a good RDBMS.

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of great answers here, I would just add that before you spend a lot of time creating translation layers and factories it's important to understand the purpose and future of your application.

Somewhere, whether it's a config mapping file, a factory, or directly in your data/business/ui layer some object/file/class/etc is going to have to have knowledge of what transpires between each layer. If swapping out layers is realistic, then creating the translation layers is useful. Other times, it just makes sense to have some layer (I usually make it in business) know about all Interfaces (or at least enough to broker between data and ui).

Again, this isn't to say all of that stuff is bad, just that it's possible [YAGNI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_ain%27t_gonna_need_it). Some DI and ORM frameworks make this stuff so easy that it's stupid not to do it. If you're using one, then it probably makes sense to get it for all it's worth.

Comment: Very well put, +1.  Also note that a lot of my translation code is re-usable across projects, and much of what isn't could be largely written by a code generator, so it's no longer much work getting something like this set up.

Comment: One of my projects is a simple intranet where I will be creating tables from scratch.  For this I will likely use ORM tool like Linq2SQL.  My main project is medium sized ecommerce site with 50+ db tables (really messy, not normalized and very few keys), so I am trying to figure the best way to tackle the data end.

Answer (score 0):

The application that I'm working on now is fairly old (in .NET terms) and uses strongly typed datasets to pass data between the data layer and the business layer. In the business layer, the data in the datasets is manually "or mapped" to business objects before being passed to the front end.

This is probably not a popular design decision though because strongly typed dataset were always somewhat controversial.

Comment: Yeagh, it would be better to refactor them away :-)

Answer (score 0):

I strongly suggest that you do it with objects. Some other way suggests that only interfaces are publics while your implementations are internal, and you expose your methods through a factory of your object, then couple your factories with a façade to finally have a single and unique entry point to your library. Then, only data objects goes through your façade, so you always know what to expect inside as outside your façade.

This way, any UI could call your library's façade, and the only thing that would remain to code is your UI.

Here's a link which I find personally very interesting that explains in summary the different design patterns: [GoF .NET Design Patterns for C# and VBNET](http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/Patterns.aspx).

If you'd rather a code sample illustrating what I'm stating, please feel free to ask.