# Revit API WinForms - Passing ComboBox value back to Command

Tags: c#, winforms, revit-api, revit

I'm trying to pass a value(an element id) from a WinForm back to the Command.cs file but I'm getting an error:

```
 System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at BatchSheetMaker.Command.Execute(ExternalCommandData commandData, String& message, ElementSet elements)
```

I'm following the youtube tutorial here and it seems fairly easy and straight forward but passing back to the Command.cs is another layer of complexity.

I have the Command.cs code wrapped in a try/catch block which just tells me that there's `nullReferenceException` however it doesn't tell me which line it's occurring at. I've [looked around](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8338495/how-to-get-error-line-number-of-code-using-try-catch) but havn't found any tips on how to make the debug show the error line. If anyone has any other pointers, that'd be helpful.

**Form1.cs**

```
 public partial class Form1 : System.Windows.Forms.Form
    {
        private UIApplication uiapp;
        private UIDocument uidoc;
        private Autodesk.Revit.ApplicationServices.Application app;
        private Document doc;

        private string myVal;

        public string MyVal
        {
            get { return myVal; }
            set { myVal = value; }
        }

        public Form1(ExternalCommandData commandData)
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            uiapp = commandData.Application;
            uidoc = uiapp.ActiveUIDocument;
            app = uiapp.Application;
            doc = uidoc.Document;
    }

    public delegate void delPassData(System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox text);
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Create a filter to get all the title block types.
            FilteredElementCollector colTitleBlocks = new FilteredElementCollector(doc);
            colTitleBlocks.OfCategory(BuiltInCategory.OST_TitleBlocks);
            colTitleBlocks.WhereElementIsElementType();

            foreach(Element x in colTitleBlocks)
            {
                comboBox1TitleBlockList.Items.Add(x.Name);
            }
        }


    private void button1Continue_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MyVal = comboBox1TitleBlockList.Text;
        }
```

**Command.cs**

```
    Form1 form1 = new Form1(commandData);
    String elementString = form1.MyVal.ToString();
    Element eFromString = doc.GetElement(elementString);
    ElementId titleBlockId = eFromString.Id;

    ViewSheet sheet = ViewSheet.Create(doc, titleBlockId);
```

Comment: If you simply comment out your try/catch stuff, the debugger will land on the problematic line.

Comment: Fair enough. I would have thought there would be more clever way to still have a try/catch and have your program tell you where it failed in the try catch while not crashing the program

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed my code to this and it started working:

**form1.cs**

```
 public string MyVal;
        //{

            //get { return myVal; }
            //set { myVal = value; }
        //}
```

[this link was helpful](https://forums.autodesk.com/t5/revit-api-forum/passing-variables-from-a-form/td-p/8374428) along with tutorials on youtube on how to pass values from form to form.

Answer (score 1):

[Run your entire add-in inside the Visual Studio debugger](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=visual+studio+debugger+add-in+Revit) and step through your code line by line. That will show you exactly where the exception is thrown and enable you to easily identify what is causing the problem.

Comment: Will do on Monday, @JeremyTammik . Thank you. just thought there'd be a way for the try/catch block to tell me where it's failing inside the try block instead of defaulting to the catch block and rolling back.

Comment: so I found the null line. it ended up being this one: `String elementString = form1.MyVal.ToString();` however I still can't find a way to send values from the form1.cs to the Command.cs. I've found a ton of ways showing how to send to another form.cs but not for a Command.cs instance. Any leads on where to find information on this?@Jeremey Tammik

Comment: that is a basic C# question that has been answered very frequently, e.g., here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2387336/how-should-i-pass-data-between-classes-and-application-layers